# How to combine probabilities for guesses

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, independence, bayesian

Let 3 people guess an object A or B.
Each person have 80% chance of being correct.

What is the probability of object being an A, if:

- all 3 of them say it is an A
- only 2 say it is an A

Can you please also refer to generalised version of this question?

EDIT: chance for A or B is 50/50

Comment: Are each persons' accuracy independent of each other?  See Bayes' Theorem.

Comment: Also necessary to clarify... what is the probability of the people being shown object A versus object B?  $0.5$?  If they in reality are only ever shown object A a miniscule part of the time, we should treat what they say with a grain of salt.  A doomsayer who takes their meds four out of five days will accurately predict that today is not the end of the world $80\%$ of the time.  If three doomsayers all say today is the end of the world, that doesn't suggest to me that it actually is... just that it they likely all forgot their meds.

Comment: Finally to clarify, is 80% their overall accuracy and if so, how is it distributed among times when they say are shown the one versus the other?  Or is it if they are shown A they will report that it is A with 80% accuracy and if shown B they report that it is B also with 80% accuracy?

Comment: @VadymB  What have you tried?  Can you show us your efforts or current thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Assume guesses are independent:

First case - the probability that all three are wrong is $.2^3=.008$.

Second case - the probability that two are wrong and one is right is $.2^2\times .8$ for each, so total is $3\times .2^2\times .8=.096$.

Comment: Note that the probability all three are wrong is a prior probability. It's the probability that all three say A if the object is actually B. This is not necessarily the same as the probability the object is actually B if all three say it is A.

Comment: @David K The object is either A or B.  If B all are wrong, if A all are right.  I don't understand your point.

Comment: My point is that in general $P(G\mid H) \neq P(H\mid G)$. You calculated a probability correctly, but is it the probability that the question asked for? For example, if $A$ is a green taxicab and $B$ is a yellow taxicab, and we know that $99\%$ of all taxicabs are yellow, we ought to give less credence to these three witnesses when they say the cab was green than we would if $80\%$ of cabs were green. Also see comments by JMoravitz under the question.

Comment: The question itself may be at fault on this matter. From the given information, your answer is all we can say without introducing additional assumptions or parameters. My comments are not so much a complaint about the answer, but they are instead a warning to the person who asked the question.

Comment: @herbsteinberg can you please expand you answer on the second case?

Comment: Second case - to get probability of wrong:  There are three combinations, depending on which one of the three got it right.  The three cases are mutually exclusive so the probabilities add.  Each of these has a probability of wrong of $0.032$, so the probability of wrong is $0.096$.